# Modify specifc td in datatable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using [`vuetable-2` (ratiw)](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2) to create the following table:

[image: screenshot of table]

This is the code that I used:

```
<vuetable ref="vuetable"
          api-url="/api/expenses"
          :fields="['cgs', 'payroll', 'others', 'rent', 'total']"
          pagination-path=""
          :http-fetch="myFetch"
          @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData">
</vuetable>

<vuetable-pagination ref="pagination" :css="css.pagination" @vuetable- 
pagination:change-page="onChangePage"></vuetable-pagination>
```

How can I make the row text in the **Total** column bold? Is it possible by using this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS. Use [`.vuetable td:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) to select the last column, and apply [`font-weight: bold`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight):

```css
.vuetable td:last-of-type {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qes4rtyf/)

If you need to add another column later, you could switch from `:last-of-type` to `:nth-last-of-type`. For example, [`td:nth-last-of-type(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type) selects the second to last column.

Comment: however, in the future I might add other column

Comment: Then, you could switch from `last-of-type` to `nth-last-of-type(x)`, where `x` is the index of the **Total** column (e.g., use `nth-last-of-type(2)` for the second to last column).